# Transfer money into two parts PayPal iOS SDK : one part is in merchant account and another in third party account

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Here are my requirement on integrating PayPal SDK in iOS app:
- we want to send the payment to dealer's PayPal account not to merchant account.
- another requirement is to pay amount in two part  one to dealer's account and another is to merchant account.

Please suggest us how to proceed for these in iOS app, so that app gets approved by Apple Store.

We are waiting for your earliest response.

Comment: at the moment this sounds like an email you should be writing to PayPal developer relations...

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your mobile app for Adaptive Payments/Chained payments. You will need to be approved for Adaptive Payments through PayPal developer.

Here is the information from the PayPal Developer Site:

The Adaptive Payments API enables merchants and developers to select the payment scenario most suitable to their needs. Merchants and developers can create applications that manage payments, payment preapprovals, and refunds. Merchants and developers can also send money peer-to-peer, split payments in both parallel and chained models, accept guest payments, , and schedule disbursements. It works on multiple platforms including the web and mobile environments.

[Adaptive Payments Basics](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/)

Here is the integration guide for IOS

[Page 17 of IOS PayPal Mobile Integration Guide has the Chained Payment Info](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_iphone.pdf)